# User input of right ascension and declination

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I thought that this would be easy but ... I want the user to input both right ascension and declination and then later in the program I will act on their input.  Here is the problem, I know how to allow the user to input declination or right ascension in decimal format (let's say declination = +29.9400)but how do I allow the user to input H:M:S like this 12 56 24 or D:arcM:arcS like this 29 56 24

Thank you

Comment: many ways to accomplish this, depending on how you want the users to format the input, but one way could be to get the data into a integer list like this: `hms = list(map(int, input("input h m s:").split(' ')))`, then  user input `29 56 24` saves into `hms` variable as a list of the integers: `[29, 56, 24]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really no reason that you can't allow the user to input the data in any way that you'd like and parse it later.  To do this, use a string:

```
 userInput = raw_input("Enter the declination as HH:MM:SS - ")
 hours, minutes, seconds = userInput.split(":")
```

Either immediately or later you can interpret these as integers, as is appropriate.  Obviously, you should do some inspection of the string to verify it is of the proper format before performing the split.

Comment: If this helped, then please upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could accept the numbers separated by a space and then have a list of the numbers split based on where the space is.
so

```
# example enter H:M:S separated by a space like 1 2 3

lNum = [int(x) for x in input().split()]



#if I enter 1 2 3 the resulting list will be[1,2,3]
#then you can just access lNum[0] lNum[1] and lNum[2] however you need
```